# Remove-SpSite error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

Trying to delete a site collection and got this error when doing so

> remove-spsite: the request could not be completed because the specified solution was not found

For some reason I couldn't delete it in GUI and powershell throws out this error.

Comment: Have you tried $site = Get-SPSite http://sharepoint/sites/site; $site.Delete()?

Comment: Do you have custom solutions in your site / farm?

Answer (score 2):

- Try to run the `Get-SPSite` to Returns all site collections.
- Check if your site collection is already listed or not.
- If it's already listed.

  - Make sure, you are running the SharePoint Management Shell as Administrator.
  - Make sure, the site collection URL has been provided successfully in the following command

> ```
> Remove-SPSite -Identity "http://sitename" -GradualDelete -Confirm:$False
> ```

This is will remove the given site collection and all included sites by using GradualDelete; confirmation has been suppressed.

If the issue still exists, try to repair your Content Database as the following.

```
$db = Get-SPContentDatabase "Content_DB_Name";
$db.Repair($false);
$db.Update();
```

**Note:**
If there is no issue the output should be `<OrphanedObjects Count="0" />` 
If the `count not equal to 0`, then set the parameter to

```
$db.repair($true)
```

Use `$true` if you want it to actually repair the database. `$false` will just list what it would repair.

Comment: thanks for that. does running db.repair takes the db offline? I have other sites that use the same content db and I want to know if it will have any effect on them?

Comment: Furst tell me is the site collection is listed , regarding your question just run$db = Get-SPContentDatabase "Content_DB_Name"; then $db.Repair($false) this not takes the db offline, if the result was <OrphanedObjects Count="0" /> so there is no issue in DB  and no need to run $db.Repair($true) $db.Update(); and the issue is related to anything else and try to check the log.

Comment: Thank you. I run $db.Repair($false) and the result was <OrphanedObjects Count="1"/>. So if I run db.repair($true) will it have any effect on the database or any of my other site collections in the mean time?